vscode shortcut command name misbehavior
In Visual Studio Code I have a keybindings.json including the following hotkey:
{
    "key": "ctrl+k n",
    "command": "changeEditorIndentation"
},

It suddenly stopped working for unknown reasons.
vscode suggested the following fix:

which worked.
However, now my other vscode instance (I have 2 instances open) stopped working, which now suggests:

This fixes my second instance but breaks my first!
So now I am in a situation, where I can only have 1 instance working at a time, depending on my choice of changeEditorIndentation1 or changeEditorIndentation2.
My other hotkeys work normally and don't have a need to add incremental numbers to their command name.
What causes this behavior, and are there fixes or workarounds?

According to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/220135 the changeEditorIndentation command has been replaced by changeEditorIndentation{num} to fix a bug, which yields the described behavior. Unfortunately this means, there is no current way to open the change indentation dialog using a hotkey consistently
